# Can I change permissons so I don't have to enter the admin password everytime I try to delete a file (or folder)?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

This has been an issue for several years. I am getting annoyed having to enter my admin password every time I want to delete or move a file or folder. They all have 777 permissions. Can I fix it?

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 xxx  staff  89513 22 Jun  2015 /xxx/yyy
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot     50 
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot     50
```

Comment: Yes you can, but there are some details missing.  Can you post the output of `ls -@l` of the folder in question?

Comment: Just added the permission of a file .. I can look for a folder if that is important.

Comment: Is this every file and folder, or specific files/folders in specific places? If the former, then that is not expected and hints at some broader problem with user accounts and permissions.
If the latter, then it might be expected, depending on what/where the file/folder is.

Comment: It is specific files and folders, I'm sure it might be expected but I asked if there was any way to stop it. Mostly they were in the sites folder and I moved them to other folders.

Comment: What version of the system are you running?

Comment: High Sierra 10.3.6